# Trying to import data from SharePoint, using Microsoft Query, and getting error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I followed the steps from this link.

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/10/29/how-to-use-microsoft-excel-to-query-a-sharepoint-list-aspx-2/

[image]

It seems like everything should work with minimal effort.  Steps 1, 2, and 3 work fine.  However, when I click the down arrow in step 4, I see nothing and of course I can't enter anything into the drop-down list.  When I click ok, I get the following error message.

The file could not be saved. You may have typed an invalid file name or be saving to an invalid (or read-only) path.

I don't think the file name is invalid and I know the path is not read-only.  I'm just trying to import data from SharePoint into Excel.  This should be a pretty simple thing.  Any ideas what could be wrong?  Thanks!!

Comment: The instructions to which you linked tell you to first export a SharePoint list to Excel using the "Export to Excel" button in the browser in SharePoint. Have you already performed that step?

Comment: Thanks for the look.  I don't have any button that says 'Export to Excel'.  It's not a list of any kind.  It's just a page with some date that I want to extract to Excel.  I tried Data > Feom Web, and pointed the URL to the relevant page.  I can't even import most of the data; it just grabs a small subset of the whole page.  It's almost like the data is sitting in different levels or something.  It doesn't make any sense to me.